# Selenium Test fails for autocomplete on google reverse lookup

Tags: java, selenium

I am missing something very basic. From whatever I could gather, I think, I need the `id` of the list that drops down as I type. Once I have the `id`, I think I can get the list and iterate through it.

Web code for the autocomplete thingy is:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
     <label>Google Map Location*</label> 
     <input id="searchTextField" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="on" required="required">
     <input id="latitude" type="text" style="display: none;" class="form-control" value=""> 
     <input id="longitude" type="text" style="display: none;"class="form-control" value="">
     <p class="help-block" style="color: #737373;">Instruction: Please drag the marker to get exact location of the IT park.</p>
</div>
```

The javascript for initializing js code is

```
        var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
```

The Selenium code is:

```
autocompleteElement = God.getWebElementById("searchTextField");
autocompleteElement.sendKeys("Airport");
List<WebElement> autoCompleteList = Initialize.getInstance().getDriver().findElements(
                        By.className("form-control");
for (WebElement autocompleteItem : autoCompleteList) {
    if (autocompleteItem.getText().contains("Pune Airport")) {
        autocompleteItem.click();
    }
    break;
}
```

I am getting `autocompleteItem` is null or empty.

**Edit 1**

I am new to `javascript` and I am inheriting this code base. What I fail to understand is how do I assign a `locator` OR an `id` to the container, so that I can iterate thru the `WebElement` and perform a `click` on my desired result.

**Edit 2**

I have added a snapshot of my autocomplete inspect element. Answers below are referring to a xpath("something very complex for me"). What do I replace the xpath with in my specific case ?

OR

What do you need to help me get List of the dropdown ?

[image: snapshot of the autocomplete dropdown]

**Edit 3**

I used class name `form-control` like this

```
List<WebElement> autoCompleteList = waitForElementByClass(
                        "form-control");
                System.out.println("autocomplete list size " + autoCompleteList.size());
                for (WebElement autocompleteItem : autoCompleteList) {
                    if (autocompleteItem.getText().contains("Wadgaon  Sheri")) {
                        System.out.println("auto complete selected " + autocompleteItem.getText());
                        autocompleteItem.click();
                        break;
                    } else
                        System.out.println("no match, tagname:" + autocompleteItem.getTagName() + "point:"
                                + autocompleteItem.getLocation());
                }
```

And got the following output. Please note `autocompleteItem.getText` returned a empty string.

```
autocomplete list size 16
no match, tagname:inputpoint:(255, 200)
no match, tagname:selectpoint:(255, 274)
no match, tagname:inputpoint:(255, 433)
no match, tagname:selectpoint:(255, 509)
no match, tagname:inputpoint:(255, 553)
no match, tagname:inputpoint:(330, 553)
no match, tagname:inputpoint:(255, 627)
no match, tagname:textareapoint:(525, 200)
no match, tagname:textareapoint:(525, 324)
no match, tagname:inputpoint:(525, 450)
no match, tagname:inputpoint:(525, 526)
no match, tagname:inputpoint:(525, 602)
no match, tagname:inputpoint:(525, 678)
no match, tagname:inputpoint:(796, 200)
no match, tagname:inputpoint:(0, 0)
no match, tagname:inputpoint:(0, 0)
```

I am now trying with class name `pac-container pac.logo` and then I'll try with `div.pac-container.pac-logo` too :). Remember, my javascript skills are not too great.

[image: pac-container pac.logo]

**Edit 4**
Now, I have tried class name as `pac-container pac.logo`, `pac-container.pac-logo`, `div.pac-container.pac.logo` and `pac-container`, the result of

> wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className(byclass)));

is that code hangs here

If I replace the line to be

> wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeSelected(God.getWebElementByClassNae(byclass)));

I get a `NoElementFoundException`.

So my closest bet to solving this is to find the class name of the damn dropdown.

```
public List<WebElement> waitForElementByClass(String byclass) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(God.getCurrentBrowser(), 2000);
        List<WebElement> elements = null;
        boolean waitForElement = true;
        System.out.print("Waiting for " + byclass);
        do {
            System.out.print(".");
            try {
                //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className(byclass)));                 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeSelected(God.getWebElementByClassNae(byclass)));
                waitForElement = false;
                System.out.println("found");
                elements = God.getWebElementsByClassName(byclass);
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                waitForElement = true;
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                waitForElement = false;
                return null;
            }
        } while (waitForElement);
        return elements;
    }
```

Comment: Firstly try to print the list to console/ save to an array and perform any action if found

Comment: Good idea.. how do I do that ? How to I refer to the list ?

Comment: Sir, why don't you give a try with thread.sleep() once?

Comment: is it possible to provide the application url?

Comment: Actually no, Its a private project. Can you let me know what else you would like to see, I can send you more code ?

Answer (score 0):

Insert code to wait for the element to be visible by using WebDriverWait. Sample below,

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10000);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("form-control")));
```

Comment: even after waiting, the list is null

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should wait for the list after typing in the `searchTextField` not for the for the input field itself. So, after typing into `searchTextField` you will have a list of suggestion and get the locator for that. In your code, wait for that locator until it is visible. Say, your locator for the auto-suggestion is `autosuggestion-list`  (assuming it is an id), so code snippet would look like:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,120); // wait 120 seconds until element is visible
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("autosuggestion-list")));
```

Hope that, you might get my point.

Comment: My question remains, how did you assume that my id is named `autosuggestion-list` ?

Comment: i told that, i assume. it was an example

Comment: The question is, how do I define a custom locator ? So that I can use that in the Selenium code to refer to it ?

Comment: i was not talking about custom locator. it was an example

Comment: I think I am not able to get across to you. What do you mean "wait for that locator".. Which locator ? Who defines the locator ?

Comment: can you come to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129232/discussion-between-siddharth-and-optimist-creeper).

Answer (score 0):

Try this. it will wait till the element is loaded and it is ready to click.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("form-control")));
```

Comment: form-control, did not results are above

Comment: Also tried elementToBeClicked, same result, NoElementFoundException

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same scenario with [Google Instant search](http://google.com) and the code is

```
    driver.get("http://google.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("airport");
    Thread.sleep(2000); // mandatory to use in this case
    List<WebElement> autoSearchList=(List<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='sbtc']/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]"));
    for ( WebElement item: autoSearchList)
    { 
        if(item.getText().contains("airport jobs"))
            item.click();
     }
```

My thoughts on this : 'autoSearchList' is showing up NULL values even if we use either Implicit wait/ Explicit wait along with specific conditions.
Only `Thread.sleep()` should be used in order to fetch the values of instant search.

I dont know why Selenium waits dont work here but you can try using sleep method to reach the output.

Comment: Can you look at my question and give me a specific answer. This example does not help much. Sorry